# a little about generic casting in java

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

In Java,everybody know Integer cannot be cast to String, which is an error at compile time.

Now for this generic case,

```
        public <T> T cast(Object o) {
            return (T) Integer.class.cast(o);//cast Integer to T
        }

        void method1() {
            String q = cast("q"); //T is String
        }
```

I just don't understand why in this case java can not warn you at compile time where Integer is cast to String. Why that? In my knowleages,the type erasure is happened after compiling.

**Edit**:I just thought that the compiler has type inference to know that T is String, so that Integer cannot be cast to.  But apparently it dosen't.

Answer (score 5):

With this

```
public <T> T cast(Object o) {
     return (T) Integer.class.cast(o);//cast Integer to T
}
```

you declare a type variable `T` that is unbounded, ie. it can be any reference type. So the `cast` to `Integer` might work or it might not.

All the compiler can do is warn you

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Integer to T

If, instead, you had given bounds to the type variable, something like

```
public <T extends CharSequence> T cast(Object o) {
    return (T) Integer.class.cast(o); // Cannot cast from Integer to T
}
```

then you would very much get a compilation error because `CharSequence` and `Integer` are not in the same inheritance hierarchy and are therefore incompatible.

In this specific case, you would get the compilation error even without the cast to `T`. This is because

```
AnyTypeName.class
```

always returns a `Class<ThatTypeName>` and `Class#cast` makes use of the generic type. In this case it would return an `Integer` and `Integer` is not convertible to `T`.

Comment: More precise about my question is that the compiler has type inference to know that T is String, so in that sense that Integer cannot be cast to. But apparently something gone wrong.

Comment: Method binding is dynamic. When compiling `cast("q")` the compiler will just look at the method signature and not the method internals.

Comment: @superChing It only knows about `String` for that particular invocation. What about other invocations?